# Removing section in view without using views. (Drupal 7 css)

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

**I'm looking to remove the tags section from the following page in Drupal**: http://www.workbooks.com/help.html

For the life of me, I can't seem to remove it within what appears to be the correct view:

`view view-community view-id-community view-display-id-page view-dom-id-`

Is there a way I can get rid of this somewhere else? I need to kiss the tag section goodbye!

[image: remove the tags section]

**UPDATE**

Adding the line, into styles.css:

```css
.view-community .views-field-name a {
  display: none;
}
```

Hides the content but leaves me with excess whitespace (where the tags were).

**UPDATE 2**

Adding the line, into styles.css

```css
.view-id-community h3 {
  display: none;
}
```

Hides the `<h3>` tag.

So the question now remains:

**How can I remove the excess whitespace now showing where the tags used to be?**

Comment: Totally remove, or just hide? The following will hide it in css .view-community {display: none;}

Comment: Adding the line: ".view-community .views-field-name a{
display: none;}" hides the content but leaves me with excess whitespace (where the tags were) and the word "tags" remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following stylesheet, `community.css` line 308, find the following class

```css
.view-community {
   clear: both;
   color: #6F6F6F;
   display: block;
   margin-right: 109px;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-right: 175px;
   margin-left: 58px;
}
```

And change it to:

```css
.view-community {
   display: none;
}
```

When I do this in Google Chrome developer tools it works. I don't see the word tools anywhere. But it is drupal so there should be a way to switch off the tags in the admin tools. just not sure where.

Comment: Sir, you are a legend! I was messing around in styles.css and you it the heart of the issue! How did you figure out the correct stylesheet?

Comment: You can see it when you inspect element with your browser developer's tool. You can also make some real time tests.

Comment: Thanks. If you have never used the developer tools you'll be pretty amazed at what they are capable of. Firefox uses Firebug and Chrome has a very good one built in. you can just right click anywhere on the browser and click on inspect element.